# How to create an .xlsx from multiple .csvs (as worksheets) without Excel on a Server using PowerShell?

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

First time poster.

I'm trying to code in PowerShell a script on my server that will do the following:

Loop through csvs all located in a single directory
Create a single Excel Workbook with each csv as a worksheet (Worksheet name as file name)
Save the Workbook in a specified directory
***Microsoft Office (hence Excel) does not exist on the Server

Any help would be greatly apprecited.

I've found below but it does not accomodate multiple csvs.
[How to export a CSV to Excel using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688468/how-to-export-a-csv-to-excel-using-powershell)

Any help would be greatly apprecited.

Comment: You cannot do this if Excel doesn't exist on the server. The answer you linked to could easily be modified to work with multiple files, but it still won't work without Excel as the ComObject won't be found

Answer (score 3):

This module https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel will allow you to read/write excel files (with multiple pages and formatting) without having Excel loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think this script does what you want, but you'll need to download EPPlus (free .NET Library) from https://epplus.codeplex.com first. Adjust your paths accordingly.

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\tmp\EPPlus 4.0.4\EPPlus.dll'
$pkg = New-Object OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(New-Object System.IO.FileInfo('c:/tmp/csvdemo/book.xlsx'))
Get-ChildItem 'c:/tmp/csvdemo/*.csv' |% { [void]$pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add($_.Name).Cells.LoadFromText($_) }
$pkg.Save()
```

Some more info over here: https://dontomp.net/read-and-write-excel-workbook-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

Here are the relevant bits from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150342/csvs-to-multi-sheet-xls-without-excel-installed-powershell).You will need to download the [spreadsheetlight](https://slpslib.codeplex.com/) module to your server.

#### Create a new xlsx file

```
$doc = New-SLDocument -WorkbookName bigxldoc -Path C:\temp -PassThru -Verbose
```

#### Import the csv files into excel

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp -Filter *.csv | 
  Import-CSVToSLDocument -WorkBookInstance $doc  -AutofitColumns -Verbose
```

#### Finally Save the document

```
$doc | Save-SLDocument -Verbose
```